# Complex Multi touch gestures in Android

Tags: android, events, touch, gesture

I am trying to implement 5 finger gestures in an app. I know I should use MotionEvent but I don't really know how. I just need the initial and final coordinates of the 5 pointers, but I really don't know how to obtain them. 
Thanks in advance for your answers. A piece of code would be enormously helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out myself, and I'll explain how.
First I used the MotionEvent.getPointerCount() to see if there are actually 5 pointers.
Next I used the pointers coordinates by calling MotionEvent.getX() and MotionEvent.getY() to handle the MotionEvents myself.